# how i can increase Featured thumbnails size?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, customization

when i open any post then 1st image show my featured image. i want to increase this size . [see it](http://www.desyfun.tk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/11.jpg) or  . i already try to increase from single.php to change this code

```
<p><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/thumbnails/thumbnail-leadimg.jpg" width="610" height="320" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" /></p>
```

but it's not working . 
my orginal code

```
<p><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/thumbnails/thumbnail-leadimg.jpg" width="610" height="225" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" /></p>
```

i don't understand how i can change it. my site http://www.dewdropzone.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the original image is not big enough. 
You can make the image display bigger via CSS :

```
.post_thumbnail{
    height: 320px
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. you can check now i change my image size. but not working. see it http://www.desyfun.tk/?p=185 .

Comment: i use this code but it's not working.......

Comment: I don't know where you put the CSS code I mentioned : I don't see it on your page. To use this code, edit the wp-content/themes/periodic/periodic/style.css file and insert the code at the end.

Comment: In this case, could you please mark the answer as the good one ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
<!-- The Post Thumbnail function is active by default, but this line of php will make it display.-->
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150, false), array("class" => "alignleft post_thumbnail")); } ?></a>
<!--Post Thumbnail Ends-->
```

This part in particular will control the size of your thumbnail regardless of the size of the image:

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150, false) 

/* width, height, option to crop 
Generally the default is set to true in order to crop the image*/
```

And the it is wrapped in anchor (link) tags so that if the person wants to view the original image size all they have to do is click on it to enlarge it and view it at full size.

You can also standardize your featured image size via your functions.php file. Just add this to your functions.php:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

// If not the standard size, state your size too
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, false );
```

This will standardize the size of the featured image thumbnail size rather than putting the sizing attribute in your theme template files.

Comment: thank you for reply. i do it but it's not working. here nothing change. please see it- http://www.desyfun.tk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/2012-10-20_065739.jpg . and also go here http://www.desyfun.tk/?p=185

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: yes, you can see it http://www.desyfun.tk/?p=185

Comment: No problem :) Glad to of helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the size of your thumbnails via set_post_thumbnail_size() the new thumbnail size applies to new uploaded images only. If you want to see the effect with existing images you need to regenerate all thumbnails. There is a plugin for this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: i use this plugin ... but it's not working.......

Comment: first you need to change thumbnail size in your functions.php. Did you change it there?
add_image_size('thumbnail-leadimg', 610, 320, true); // Lead Image Thumbnail Size

Comment: yes i change it. but not working....